# Extract files with cpio where one or more paths may contain spaces

Tags: centos, cpio

We have a cpio archive that was created by generating a file that contains a list of absolute paths to be included in the archive. (one absolute path per line of a plain text file) The command to generate the archive is essentially:

```
cat list-of-files | cpio -ocvB > preserved.cpio
```

We later need to extract files from that archive. We again want to use a file that contains a list of files to be extracted (some subset of all of the files in the archive, again with the format of one absolute path per line of a plain text file).

```
cpio -icuBdmv `cat files-to-extract` < preserved.cpio
```

This works fine unless one of the paths contains a space. Generating the archive is fine, but when extracting the files, any file with a space in the name is silently skipped. All other paths in `files-to-extract` are successfully extracted.

I've been playing at the console trying to come up with some way to work around this, but to no avail. If I specify a single file with a space in the name and wrap it in quotes, the file is extracted successfully:

```
# This extracts the file successfully
cpio -icuBdmv "/foo/bar/some file.txt" < preserved.cpio
```

So I could read `files-to-extract` in a loop and extract each file one at a time, but these archives can be large (multiple GB), so that is dreadfully slow.

I tried a couple things to somehow try to either escape the spaces in file paths or quote each path value, but nothing I've tried has worked.

```
# Still skips the file with spaces:
cpio -icuBdmv `cat files-to-extract | sed 's/ /\\ /'` < preserved.cpio
# Extracts no files, even the ones without spaces:
cpio -icuBdmv `cat files-to-extract | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'` < preserved.cpio
```

It would really be nice to be able to do this extraction with a single run of cpio rather than having to loop and extract one file at a time. I'm sure this is just a problem with how I am providing those values to cpio, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Probably not relevant, but just for completeness: this is on CentOS 7.2, using GNU cpio 2.11

Comment: Quoting in the result of `$( )` substitution doesn't work, unless eval'ed or otherwise reparsed which gets very tricky. What you can do is set `IFS='\n'` before the command, preferably in a subshell so it automatically reverts: `( IFS='\n'; cpio -icuBdmv $(cat names) <archive )`. But note if the substituted results are too big for your system's ARG_MAX this will fail, while `xargs` as in @Ian's answer will break it into groups small enough to run but still much larger and more efficient than one at a time.

Comment: cas' solution is the simple, obvious one that I failed to notice while looking at the man page, as they sorta implied :) I'm not a fan of `info`, but still, I should have seen the `-E` option where I was looking. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: info docs are a lot nicer to read if you use `pinfo` rather than the FSF's own `info`.  The `pinfo` UI is kind of like `lynx`, but for info files.  I'd still prefer to have a proper man page (with at least a summary description of each option) as well as the .info reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cpio` has a `-E` (`--pattern-file`) option, which allows you to read the list of filenames from a file instead of (or as well as) providing the filenames on the command line.  For example:

```
cpio -icuBdmv -E files-to-extract < preserved.cpio
```

`cpio` also has `-F` to specify an archive name (instead of using stdin/stdout).  `-I` and `-O` are similar but work instead of stdin or stdout respectively.

e.g. you can specify the archive with `-F` and provide the files list on stdin:

```
cpio -icuBdmv -F preserved.cpio < files-to-extract
```

or use both `-E` and `-F`

```
cpio -icuBdmv -E files-to-extract -F preserved.cpio
```

---

BTW, with many GNU programs (including `cpio`, the man pages are almost useless, but they are well-documented in .info files.  On some Linux distributions, the info docs are often separate packages (e.g. on debian, `cpio-doc`), so you'll need to install them as well as an info reader (such as GNU `info` or `pinfo`)

anyway, here's some relevant extracts from the `cpio` info pages:

> `-E FILE`, `--pattern-file=FILE`
>
> Read additional patterns specifying filenames to extract or list from FILE.  The lines of FILE are treated as if they had been non-option arguments to cpio.  This option is used in copy-in mode,

and

> `-F ARCHIVE`, `--file=ARCHIVE`
>
> Archive filename to use instead of standard input or output.  To use a tape drive on another machine as the archive, use a filename that starts with `HOSTNAME:`, where HOSTNAME is the name or IP address of the machine.  The hostname can be preceded by a username and an `@` to access the remote tape drive as that user, if you have permission to do so (typically an entry in that user's `~/.rhosts` file).

Answer (score 3):

Spaces in file names can be tricky, but I think this might help.

Instead of `cat`ing your files-to-extract, try feeding it through `xargs` substituting the NULL character for EOL.

Something like

```
tr '\n' '\0' < list-of-files | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'cpio -icuBdmv "{}" < preserved.cpio'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: given that the source file `list-of-files` didn't start off with NUL-separated records, `tr` won't and can't magically make it so.  you may as well just just `xargs -d'\n'` .

Comment: @cas I don't think that's correct. `tr` is changing the carriage-returns into NULL characters, then `xargs` is using those as record separators to feed to `cpio`.

However, it doesn't really matter, you provided a better and more thoroughly explained answer anyway :-)

Comment: yes, your `tr` command **is** changing newlines (NOT carriage returns) into NULs.  However, if `list-of-files` contains any filenames with a newline in them (newline is an annoying but completely valid character in a filename), it will convert those newlines along with all the others.  There is no way to tell the difference between a newline at the end of a filename and a newline embedded in the middle filename, therefore you can't convert newline-separated into NUL-separated.   That's why I said that you may as well use `xargs -d'\n'`.  It works exactly the same, without the pointless `tr`.

Comment: and without fooling yourself or others that you're properly handling ALL valid filenames.  Which is where the problem lies.  Using `tr` like this doesn't matter here (because cpio takes a \n-delimited list of names, anyway).  The danger is in believing that the `tr` actually does something **useful** and **worthwhile** here (it doesn't), and then using it in a context where it does matter.

Comment: @cas That makes sense. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: you're welcome.  I'm glad i managed to explain what i meant the second time around....it's obvious once you know it, but not easy to explain to someone who doesn't already know it.   (and yes, I used to do things like your `tr` command a long time ago.  In many cases, it works.  When it doesn't, it can really ruin your day.  I learnt the hard way.  Fortunately, I had backups).